# Restrict the Google AutoComplete API to show only nearby locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, autocomplete, ios9

For location finding Google AutoComplete works good but its returning the search results all over the world. I want to restrict the search results either with in the 1000 meter radius or in a city. I followed this [google link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) to integrate the autocomplete search. Only this below code used in project

```
-(void)autoComplete
{
    GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
    acController.delegate = self;
 [self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
// Handle the user's selection.
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // Do something with the selected place.
    NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
    NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
    NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
}

- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    // TODO: handle the error.
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}

// User canceled the operation.
- (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use apple maps to do the same ?

Comment: whats the purpose you used this auto complete ... may be show in table view else , panorama view

Comment: this is just a part of maps.. if you aware of ola search bar , there you can see the nearby locations by consumer input. i need to implement that. its perfect for showing the list of locations by conumer input but if user "A" its showing america, algeria , arizona etc instead of this I want to filter it and display the near by locations @BharathVankireddy & Anbu.Karthik

Comment: I am big hater of google dev frameworks bcause i feel apple frameworks like vanila flavoured icecream, but I need to implement google autocomplete functionality this was my seniors decision i dont want argue them to change it , they have enough reasons to tell why google for this task @BharathVankireddy

Comment: Place Autocomplete isn't the appropriate API to use if you want nearby locations. Even so with the iOS client, there's no way of setting it. If you check Google Place API documentation, you can use Place Search (web service call) [nearby search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) with what you intend to have.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot 100% restrict it, But you can give more priority to your city by specifying its northeast and southwest corners, Here is the code

```
GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
acController.delegate = self;

CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(northEastLati, northEastLongi);
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(southWestLati, southWestLongi);
acController.autocompleteBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                            coordinate:southWest];

[self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now you will get 99% of result will be belongs to your city. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Swift Version.

If your autocompleteController is being presented, refresh it by calling 
**updateCoordinateBoundsOnAutoCompleteController()**

```
/* Returns Bounds */
func getCoordinateBounds(latitude:CLLocationDegrees ,
                                 longitude:CLLocationDegrees,
                                 distance:Double = 0.001)->GMSCoordinateBounds{
            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude,
                                                longitude: longitude)
            let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + distance, longitude: center.longitude + distance)
            let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - distance, longitude: center.longitude - distance)

            return GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast,
                                       coordinate: southWest)

        }

/* Refreshes AutoCompleteController */
func updateCoordinateBoundsOnAutoCompleteController(){
        autocompleteController.viewWillAppear(true)
        autocompleteController.viewDidAppear(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Updated Code for Swift 5.

```
 let autoCompleteVC = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autoCompleteVC.delegate = self
        let addressFilter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        addressFilter.type = .noFilter
        
        if let currentLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
           
            let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLocation.latitude + 0.1, longitude: currentLocation.longitude + 0.1)
            let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLocation.latitude - 0.1, longitude: currentLocation.longitude - 0.1)
          
            addressFilter.locationBias = GMSPlaceRectangularLocationOption(northEast, southWest);
           
        }
        autoCompleteVC.autocompleteFilter = addressFilter
        present(autoCompleteVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```